# Create angular page in Django to consume data from JSON

Tags: angularjs, django, django-templates

In an angular controller I have a list of items:

```
app.controller('MainController', ['$scope', function($scope) { 
    $scope.items = [
                    {"foo":"bar 1"},
                    {"foo":"bar 2"},
                    {"foo":"bar n"}
                   ]
}]);
```

The following html page, based on angular, displays a list of item:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>list</title>
<script src= "http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.14/angular.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body data-ng-app="myApp">

<div data-ng-controller="MainController">
  <p>List of items:</p>
  <ul>
    <li data-ng-repeat="item in items">
      {{ item.foo }}
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

How can I integrate that html page in Django and bind it to a Django URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add the angular app as a simple template view in Django

views.py

```
def index(request):
    return render(request, 'yourhtml.html', {})
```

urls.py

```
....    
url(r'^your_url/$', views.index),
....
```

Then the index.html file can have your angular code